# Classifying images using adjusted CNN tutorial - system is jumbling the output

Tags: python, tensorflow

Sorry, this is a long one!

I am 80% sure that the problem is that I don't fully understand how `tensorflow` uses the `tf.train.batch` function to queue data.

I am trying to adapt one of the `tensorflow` tutorials to classify a large number of images.

Tutorial can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn

I have built some modules which can encode my raw data in the same format that cifar10 uses. I am using this to construct training and evaluation data which the program is able to evaluate to a high degree of accuracy. Accuracy varies depending on the quality of the imagesets I put in. To keep things simple I have trained it using 32x32 monochrome tiles of either yellow or blue (category 0 and 1 respectively). Conveniently the network is able to identify whether it is being given a yellow or blue tile with 100% accuracy.

I have also been able to adapt `cifar10_eval.py` to output predictions rather than an accuracy percentage. This allows me to feed in un-classified data and output predictions as a list. To do this I have exchanged the statement:
    `top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)`
for:
    `output_2 = tf.argmax(logits, 1)`
I have added a variable and a boolean to the eval_once function call to allow it to access the definition for "output_2" and to let me switch between this and "top_k_op" depending on whether I am in evaluation mode or if I am predicting new data.

So far so good. This method works for small amounts of input data but fails as soon as I want to output more than 128 classifications. Not coincidentally 128 is the batch size.

In theory the first item (3073 bytes) in the binary should correspond to the first item in the list which is churned out when I am predicting new data. This happens for inputs of up to 128 images but the data gets jumbled up when I try to categorise more images. Actually, some of the predictions are lost completely!

There are a couple of reasons that this happens. The tutorial isn't designed to care about the order in which data is read or processed, just that individual images correspond with their labels. Originally the data loss was randomised(!) but I have managed to remove the random element by removing multi-threading (threads = 1 rather than 16) and stopped it from shuffling filenames.

`filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, shuffle=False)`

string_input_producer has a hidden/optional argument which shuffles the file names. For model evaluation I have set this to false as above.

However.... I am still stuck with jumbled data loss when evaluating data larger than a single batch.

Does anyone know why this happens and have any ideas about how it could be fixed?

In theory I could redesign the code to rebuild the graph and evaluate it for 128 images at a time. However, I want to classify millions of images and feel that I'd be asking for trouble trying to open a new graph instance per batch.

PS, I've done my homework:
I have verified that my initial data to binary conversion works by running a program which can read cifar10-style files and interpret it as a big tile of images. I have run this code on both the original cifar10 binaries and my own binaries and am able to reconstruct both perfectly.

When I encode uncategorised data I add a category label of zero to make sure the tutorial can read the file. However, I make sure that this label is chucked away at the file reading stage and thus is not used when generating a list of predictions.

I have verified the output predictions by printing the list directly onto the screen as a python output and also by using it to assemble a PNG image which can be compared with the original inputs. This verification works perfectly for small batch sizes and starts to fall apart in larger batch sizes.

I've also made some modifications to the tutorial not discussed in this post. These are simple modifications such as changing the number of categories to 2 rather than 10. Am confident that this is not the issue.

PPS, here is a copy of some functions from the modified script. I haven't pasted everything because this question is already huge:

from cifar10_eval:

```
def eval_once(saver, summary_writer, top_k_op, output_2, summary_op, mapping=False):
  """Run Eval once.
  Args:
    saver: Saver.
    summary_writer: Summary writer.
    top_k_op: Top K op.
    summary_op: Summary op.
  """
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
      # Restores from checkpoint
      saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
      # Assuming model_checkpoint_path looks something like:
      #   /my-favorite-path/cifar10_train/model.ckpt-0,
      # extract global_step from it.
      global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
    else:
      print('No checkpoint file found')
      return

    # Start the queue runners.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    try:
      threads = []
      for qr in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS):
        threads.extend(qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, daemon=True,
                                         start=True))

      num_iter = int(math.ceil(FLAGS.num_examples / FLAGS.batch_size))
      true_count = 0  # Counts the number of correct predictions.
      total_sample_count = num_iter * FLAGS.batch_size
      step = 0
      output=[]
      if mapping:   # if in mapping mode generate a map, if in default mode (variable set to False by default) then tally predictions instead.
          while step < num_iter and not coord.should_stop():
            step += 1
            hold = sess.run(output_2)
            print(hold)
            for i in range (len(hold)):        
                output.append(hold[i])

  return(output)
```

from cifar10_input:

```
def inputs(mapping, data_dir, batch_size):
  """Construct input for CIFAR evaluation using the Reader ops.
  Args:
    mapping: bool, indicating if one should use the raw or pre-classified eval data set.
    data_dir: Path to the CIFAR-10 data directory.
    batch_size: Number of images per batch.
  Returns:
    images: Images. 4D tensor of [batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3] size.
    labels: Labels. 1D tensor of [batch_size] size.
  """
  filelist = os.listdir(data_dir)
  filenames = []

  if mapping:
#      from Raw_Image_Processor import file_name
      for f in filelist:
            if f.startswith("raw_batch"):
                filenames.append(os.path.join(data_dir, f))
      num_examples_per_epoch = NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN
  else:
      for f in filelist:
            if f.startswith("eval_batch"):
                filenames.append(os.path.join(data_dir, f))
      num_examples_per_epoch = NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL

  for f in filenames:
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(f):
      raise ValueError('Failed to find file: ' + f)

  # Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, shuffle=False)

  # Read examples from files in the filename queue.
  read_input = read_cifar10(filename_queue)
  reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32)

  height = IMAGE_SIZE
  width = IMAGE_SIZE

  # Image processing for evaluation.
  # Crop the central [height, width] of the image.
  resized_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(reshaped_image,
                                                         height, width)

  # Subtract off the mean and divide by the variance of the pixels.
  float_image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(resized_image)

  # Set the shapes of tensors.
  float_image.set_shape([height, width, 3])
  read_input.label.set_shape([1])

  # Ensure that the random shuffling has good mixing properties.
  min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
  min_queue_examples = int(num_examples_per_epoch *
                           min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)

  # Generate a batch of images and labels by building up a queue of examples.
  return _generate_image_and_label_batch(float_image, read_input.label,
                                         min_queue_examples, batch_size,
                                         shuffle=False)
```

from cifar10_input:

```
def _generate_image_and_label_batch(image, label, min_queue_examples,
                                    batch_size, shuffle):
  """Construct a queued batch of images and labels.
  Args:
    image: 3-D Tensor of [height, width, 3] of type.float32.
    label: 1-D Tensor of type.int32
    min_queue_examples: int32, minimum number of samples to retain
      in the queue that provides of batches of examples.
    batch_size: Number of images per batch.
    shuffle: boolean indicating whether to use a shuffling queue.
  Returns:
    images: Images. 4D tensor of [batch_size, height, width, 3] size.
    labels: Labels. 1D tensor of [batch_size] size.
  """
  # Create a queue that shuffles the examples, and then
  # read 'batch_size' images + labels from the example queue.
  num_preprocess_threads = 16
  if shuffle:
    images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [image, label],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
        capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size,
        min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
  else:
    images, label_batch = tf.train.batch(
        [image, label],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=1,
        capacity=1,
        enqueue_many = False)

  # Display the training images in the visualizer.
  tf.summary.image('images', images)

  return images, tf.reshape(label_batch, [batch_size])
```

Edit:
Partial solution is given in the comments below. Information loss is dependent on batch size so it turns out that increasing the batch size (in mapping mode only) is an effective fix.

However, I'm still unsure why it loses and/or scrambles information when the batch size is exceeded. Presumably the batches are taken is some non-sequential order. I don't need it to take the project forwards but if someone could explain how or why this happens it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 2:
It's back! I've set the batch size to be equivalent to one binary file (in my case roughly 10,000 images). Data is not lost or jumbled within this batch but when I try to process multiple files (about 30) it mixes up the batches a little rather than outputting them on a FIFO basis.

A picture is probably the easiest way for you to see what is going on:
[classification map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX8VD.png)
This is a reconstructed image of a rock face from which the classifier has been trained to recognize three categories. As you can see the reconstruction is mostly smooth. However, there are two clean breaks near the top of the image where a batch (or 3) has been outputted in non-chronological order. These should have appeared at the bottom of the image rather than near the top.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this, but maybe I'm looking for the wrong symptoms. I (as you mention) set `num_threads=1` on line 131 of cfar10_input.py, and turn off filename shuffling, and I get exactly the same loss every time when running `python3 cifar10_eval.py --eval_interval_secs=0 --num_examples=1000 --batch_size=1000`. It does vary a bit with `num_threads=16`.

Comment: My description may be a bit misleading. The data loss is not "random" per se but doesn't follow any easily determined pattern.

Comment: However, you have provided a good workaround. It hadn't occurred to me to set the batch size very high. I've put in a line to set the batch size to correspond with the number of input images in mapping mode and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, so it only shows up with multiple batches? Just a guess, but could it be an issue with the trailing batch size? The default is 128, and it looks like the eval script is rounding up, so unless the number of examples is divisible by 128 you won't get "clean" epochs with all of the examples.

Comment: Reasonable guess but unfortunately that isn't the cause. My reader program works out how many predictions it should be fed and automatically bins the additional predictions created by rounding errors. Also it wouldn't account for the mild shuffling effect I'm getting when reading large numbers of files (I've updated question with a picture to show this).

Comment: Huh. And the files are going into the `string_input_producer` in the correct/desired order? One way to narrow it down would be to add a `value = tf.Print(value, [result.key])` statement after the [reader.read call in cifar10_input](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L80). Are those keys (filename:position) in the correct order?

Comment: Good spot. It was reading them 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 which I have fixed by adding leading zeros to the filenames. With that and using the large batch size the system can now handle huge chunks of data (over 200,000 at a time rather than 128). Question answered, cheers!